# Output the solved time and date in minizinc with assert function

Tags: minizinc

Imagine I have below code and it would output the assert statement since the condition is not met.

```
int: x =40;
var int:y;

constraint y=x;
```

Now imagine I am getting the value for x from a data file where user can enter any value from their end.
But I am limiting user to enter only positive figures to x.(X cannot be negative figures).

```
constraint assert(x>=0,"Please enter a positive value to X");

solve satisfy;
```

Imagine user input -2 so it will output the above statement.I need to print the date and time with above statement.(At least time).Is there any method to do that in minizinc.

Comment: There is no built-in function in MiniZInc for this. A suggestion is that you run this via a wrapper (e.g. the Python MiniZinc package) to catch the error and then print date and time.

Comment: Thanks  @hakank for the reply.Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'll convert my comment as an answer, so you can accept it if you want.)

There is no built-in function in MiniZinc for doing this. A suggestion is that you run this via a wrapper (e.g. the Python MiniZinc package, see below) to catch the error and then print date and time.

The Python MiniZinc package is here: https://minizinc-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Comment: Thanks @hakank Yes this is accepted.I will check the python package.